# React native error [TypeError: Network request failed] - error

Tags: android, react-native, fetch-api

I'm trying to make an API call to my back-end hosted in AWS (nginx + certbot)
but every time, I run the application I am getting the following error:

> error [TypeError: Network request failed]

The following is the snippet of the code which I'm using for fetch request:

```
fetch(baseUrl+"/myapi")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => console.log(result))
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

I have tried it on postman its working perfectly, as well it is working on the browser not getting the missing part in the code.

I'm running it on Android 10,
RN 0.64.0

Edit: I have tried it on Android 7 and it is working perfectly the problem it is giving me is in Android 10.

Any advice is really appreciated.

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what it could be. I'd test that device/emulator has internet connection. If you are trying to connect to an API on your machine you won't be able to uses localhost as that will actually relative to the android device.

Comment: this is not happening in the localhost im connecting to the AWS server for API

Comment: try use this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29845